# Play! framework don't accept my @MappedSuperclass without @Entity annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework

**Important**: please note that I'm talking about Play! framework version 1 (1.2.6), not 2.x

I have 2 entities in my Play! **v1** application, like that:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_FOO")
public class Foo extends GenericModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    public String name;

    public static List<Foo> paginate(int start, int count) {
        return all().from(start).fetch(count);
    }
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_BAR")
public class Bar extends GenericModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    public String name;

    public static List<Bar> paginate(int start, int count) {
        return all().from(start).fetch(count);
    }
}
```

In my controller, I can do that without problem:

```
public static void index() {
    List<Foo> foo = Foo.paginate(1, 5);
    List<Bar> bar = Bar.paginate(2, 5);
    render(foo, bar);
}
```

As you can see, these 2 entities are quite similar, so I created a super class to regroup common methods:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class MyGenericModel<T> extends GenericModel {

    public static <T> List<T> paginate(int start, int count) {
        return all().from(start).fetch(count);
    }

}
```

and make it as the parent of my entities, for example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_FOO")
public class Foo extends MyGenericModel<Foo> {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    public String name;

}
```

However, with this modification, I get the following error when I try to call `Foo.paginate()` method:

```
UnsupportedOperationException occured : Please annotate your JPA model with @javax.persistence.Entity annotation.

play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: Please annotate your JPA model with @javax.persistence.Entity annotation.
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:237)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Please annotate your JPA model with @javax.persistence.Entity annotation.
```

It seems that Play! wants me to annotate `MyGenericModel` with `@Entity` annotation, which I don't want.
I thought that annotating `MyGenericModel` with `@MappedSuperclass` would help me to avoid this problem, but it is not the case.

What did I make wrong, and how to make it work correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't call the function **all()** from your class **MyGenericModel** because that function is enhanced at runtime and only for classes annotated with **@Entity**.

Possible solution could be that you use your own entity manager for your queries.

Or you could go back to your first option, there was nothing wrong with that :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just 2 comments: 1. Why GenericModel (from Play! API) work then? It uses the `all()` methods (as well as the others) 2. I simplified my question, but in fact I have 20 entities concerned, so multiple copy-pastes.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately (this is also my pain) Generics are not yet supported by Ebean:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/ebean/generics/ebean/QWjpI0LRCiA/io-Lm_gfYE4J

Comment: Thanks for this comment, however I'm using Play! 1, not Play! 2, and except if I'm wrong, `Ebean` is only used in v2...